# prove or disprove invertible matrix with given equations

Tags: matrices

Given a non-scalar matrix $A$ in size $n\times n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ that maintains the following equation 
$$A^2 + 2A = 3I$$
given matrix $B$ in size $n\times n$ too $$B = A^2 + A- 6I$$
Is $B$ an invertible matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative version to the other excellent answers by **Quark** and **user1551**.

Note first, as the others did, that $(A + 3 I) (A - I) = 0$, and $B = (A - 2 I)(A + 3 I)$.

Then
$$
B (A - I) = 0.
$$
So if $A \ne I$, then $B$ is definitely *not* invertible.

If $A = I$, as noted by **Quark**, then $B = -4 I$ is invertible.

But **Tharsis** (thanks!) made me notice that $A$ is non-scalar by assumption, so the case $A = I$ is excluded (although easy to deal with).

Comment: It is required that $A$ be non-scalar, so $A \ne I$ and $B$ is not invertible.

Comment: @Tharsis, oh, thanks, I had not noticed that, will fix.

Comment: hi,thanks for your response. do you mean that $B = $0 (the zero matrix)?

Comment: @idannik, you're welcome. No, I mean non-invertible, as $B$ invertibile and $B (A - I) = 0$ would imply $A - I = 0$.

Comment: thanks again for your explanation . you have helped me. have a nice day mate!

Comment: I like this unconventional proof! +1

Answer (score 0):

It depends, If you factorize the first equation you get,
$$(A-I)*(A+3I)=0$$

This implies$\; \det(A-I)\;\; or\;\; \det(A-3I)\;$ must be zero.

Now factorizing B gives you (A-2I)*(A+3I)

So $\det(B) = \det(A-2I)*\det(A+3I)$

If $\det(A-3I)$ is zero from the first condition, then $\det(B)$ is also zero, so B is not invertible.

But, if $\det(A-I)$ is zero and not $\det(A-3I)$, I don't think anything can be said

(not very sure, but I can give a example: If you take A=I, the first equation is satisfied, and B comes out to be -4I which is invertible...)

Comment: Please check your LaTeX to write properly mathematics in this site, in the FAQ section. Also, $\,A=I\,$ is not an option by assumption...

Comment: $A^2+2A-3I=(A-I)(A\color{red}{+}3I)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The first equation implies that $A^2+2A-3I=(A-I)(A+3I)=0$. Hence the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ of $A$ divides $(x-1)(x+3)$. What happens if $x+3$ is not a factor of $m_A(x)$?

Comment: hello.thanks for your response . could you explain your answer.

Comment: @idannik If $x+3$ is not a factor of the minimal polynomial of $A$ (I hope you have learnt what a minimal polynomial is), then the minimal polynomial must be equal to $x-1$, which means $A=I$, which contradicts our assumption. Therefore $x+3$ must be a factor of the minimal polynomial, i.e. $A+3I$ is singular. But then $B$ is singular too.

Comment: oh, I got it . thanks